# Active sessions on specific page

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm aware of how to get a total count of active sessions for your application but is it possible to get a count of active sessions on a specific page?

For example if you had 2 users currently viewing 'page.aspx' then it would report 2 users active for this page.

I'm only aware of being able to query the current session in codebehind by using `Page.Session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never know for certain if someone is viewing a page or not: the web is both disconnected and stateless.

The technique is, on every request, to log the page requested; every time that user (uniquely identified, somehow) moves to another page then their "last page requested" is updated, along with a timestamp, you might assume that if no subsequent request is made after say, 5 minutes, then they've closed the browser window.

An alternative is to use a Javascript poller or window event handler, but that's unreliable and you must never depend on this in your application.